# Issue in setting up Hyperledger Explorer:- ReferenceError: host_port is not defined

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-explorer

I am trying to setup hyperledger explorer for the fabric swarm network having 3 orgs.

{

```
 "network-configs": {
         "network-1": {
         "version": "1.0",
             "clients": {
                  "client-1": {
                     "tlsEnable": false,
                      "organization": "StancOrgMSP",
                      "channel": "masterchannel",
                       "credentialStore": {
                                "path": "./tmp/credentialStore_Org1/credential",
                                "cryptoStore": {
          "path": "./tmp/credentialStore_Org1/crypto"
                                  }
                       }
                    }
            },
             "channels": {
                    "masterchannel": {
                          "peers": {
                              "HOSTA.peerStanc_com": {}
                           },
                           "connection": {
                                        "timeout": {
                                            "peer": {
                                               "endorser": "6000",
                                                "eventHub": "6000",
                                                 "eventReg": "6000"
                                              }
                                      }
                           }
                       }
                   },
                   "organizations": {
                           "StancOrgMSP": {
                              "mspid": "StancOrgMSP",
                              "fullpath": false,
                              "adminPrivateKey": {
                               "path": "/home/ubuntu/ST/fabric-swarm/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/peerStanc_com/users/Admin@peerStanc_com/msp/keystore"
                             },
                              "signedCert": {
                                 "path": "/home/ubuntu/ST/fabric-swarm/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/peerStanc_com/users/Admin@peerStanc_com/msp/signcerts"
                            }
                        },
                         "StancOrgAMSP": {
                              "mspid": "StancOrgAMSP",
                              "adminPrivateKey": {
                                "path": "/home/ubuntu/ST/fabric-swarm/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/peerStancA_com/users/Admin@peerStancA_com/msp/keystore"
                           },
                             "signedCert": {
                                "path": "/home/ubuntu/STANC/A-HYPERLEDGER/fabric-swarm/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/peerStancA_com/users/Admin@peerStancA_com/msp/signcerts"
                          }
                       },
                      "StancOrgBMSP": {
                           "mspid": "StancOrgBMSP",
                           "adminPrivateKey": {
                                "path": "/home/ubuntu/ST/fabric-swarm/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/peerStancB_com/users/Admin@peerStancB_com/msp/keystore"
                         },
                         "signedCert": {
                                 "path": "/home/ubuntu/ST/fabric-swarm/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/peerStancB_com/users/Admin@peerStancB_com/msp/signcerts"
                       }
                    },
                    "StancOrdererMSP": {
                          "mspid": "StancOrdererMSP",
                          "adminPrivateKey": {

        "path": "/home/ubuntu/ST/fabric-swarm/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/StancOrdr_com/users/Admin@StancOrdr_com/msp/keystore"
                           }
                        }
                 },
                "peers": {
                    "HOSTA.peerStanc_com": {
                       "tlsCACerts": {
                            "path": "/home/ubuntu/ST/fabric-swarm/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/peerStanc_com/peers/HOSTA.peerStanc_com/tls/ca.crt"
                       },
                       "url": "grpc://localhost:7051",
                       "eventUrl": "grpc://localhost:7053",
                       "grpcOptions": {
                           "ssl-target-name-override": "HOSTA.peerStanc_com"
                        }
                       }
                     },
                     "orderers": {
                           "StancOrderer.StancOrdr_com": {
                            "url": "grpc://localhost:7050"
                            }
                       }
                    },
                   "network-2": {}
                 },
                  "configtxgenToolPath": "/home/ubuntu/ST/bin",
                 "license": "Apache-2.0"
    }
```

I have updated the config by adding 3 peers of each orgs in peer section.But the issue still persists.
I have attached the logs for the reference.

The following is the log from app directory.

```
[2019-01-21 19:31:41.108] [DEBUG] FabricClient - then privateKeyPEM data
[2019-01-21 19:31:41.109] [DEBUG] FabricClient - then signedCertPEM data
[2019-01-21 19:31:41.111] [DEBUG] FabricClient - then user
[2019-01-21 19:31:41.111] [DEBUG] FabricClient - Successfully created user [client-1_StancOrdererMSPAdmin] for client [client-1]
[2019-01-21 19:31:41.112] [DEBUG] FabricClient - Client.createUser missing required organization.
[2019-01-21 19:31:41.112] [DEBUG] FabricClient - Client.createUser missing required organization.
```

The following is the log from console directory

```
ReferenceError: host_port is not defined
    at FabricClient.initializeChannelFromDiscover (/home/ubuntu/HYPERLEDGER-EXPLORER1/blockchain-explorer/app/platform/fabric/FabricClient.js:408:17)
    at <anonymous>
Received kill signal, shutting down gracefully
Closed out connections
```

Can anyone face this issue?How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I've also got this error. Looking at the source file in the docker container, you can find these lines

```
logger.error(
  'Peer configuration is not found in config.json for peer %s and url %s , so peer status not work for the peer',
  host_port,
  requesturl
);
```

So the error is due to the use of the variable **host_port** which was not defined before. However, the original error is that your explorer config.json does not contain all the necessary peer-configurations. For example, you have only defined **HOSTA.peerStanc_com** whilst your network contains other peers (found by the discovery service).

Answer (score 0):

All nodes need to be defined in the config. JSON file. Check that your config. JSON is defined correctly according to the document. Because the node found through service discovery is not defined in the file, the error will be reported.